# Getting error while making column using DataFrame and Pandas

Tags: pandas, ipython, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

[I am following this example tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bensadeghi/pyspark-churn-prediction/blob/master/churn-prediction.ipynb)

I am using spark1.5.1 and python 3.5 anaconda distribution.My code was running fine untill I reached at 7th cell this

```
pd.DataFrame(CV_data.take(5), columns=CV_data.columns)
```

I am getting error on this cell

```
Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d3dfeab0b119> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(CV_data.take(5), columns=CV_data.columns)
C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in take(self, num)
303 with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
304 port = self._sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe(
--> 305 self._jdf, num)
306 return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
307
C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in _call_(self, *args)
536 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
537 return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538 self.target_id, self.name)
539 
540 for temp_arg in temp_args:
C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
34 def deco(*a, **kw):
35 try:
---> 36 return f(*a, **kw)
37 except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
38 s = e.java_exception.toString()
C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
298 raise Py4JJavaError(
299 'An error occurred while calling
{0} {1} {2}
.\n'.
--> 300 format(target_id, '.', name), value)
301 else:
302 raise Py4JError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 18, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 111, in main
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 106, in process
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 1417, in <lambda>
func = lambda _, it: map(lambda x: returnType.toInternal(f(*x)), it)
File "<ipython-input-7-6db2287430d4>", line 5, in <lambda>
KeyError: False
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1314)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$.takeAndServe(python.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe(python.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 111, in main
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 106, in process
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "C:\Users\InAm-Ur-Rehman\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 1417, in <lambda>
func = lambda _, it: map(lambda x: returnType.toInternal(f(*x)), it)
File "<ipython-input-7-6db2287430d4>", line 5, in <lambda>
KeyError: False
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
... 1 more
In [ ]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a typo, there is a confusion between the boolean False and the string 'False' somewhere.

In python you can define both dictionaries with no error

```
strf={'False' : 0}
boolf={False : 0}
```

you are calling strf[False], so you get a KeyError.

Comment: I couldn't understand..where I made the typo?

Comment: I can't guess if you don't paste your code. Probably binary_map, just check that your code corresponds exactly to the tutorial.

Comment: I explained the error you posted I won't do your homework

Comment: well your explanation didn't solve my porblem. thanks anyway

Comment: that's because you did not post your problem